# Convergence region of local and global zeta functions

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $\chi = \prod_{v} \chi_{v}: \mathbb{A}^{\times}/F^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ be a finite order Hecke character and let $\Phi = \prod_{v} \Phi_{v}$ be a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{A}$. Define local and global zeta functions as
$$
\zeta_{v}(s, \chi_v, \Phi_v) = \int_{F_{v}^{\times}} \Phi_{v}(x)\chi_{v}(x) |x|_{v}^{s}d^{\times}x_{v} \\
\zeta(s, \chi, \Phi) = \int_{\mathbb{A}^{\times}} \Phi(x) \chi(x) |x|^{s} d^{\times} x
$$
One can show that local zeta functions absolutely converges when $\Re(s) > 0$, and global zeta function absolutely converges when $\Re(s) > 1$. 
I want to know what makes convergence region to be shifted by one from local to global.

Here's more explicit example - consider the usual Riemann zeta function 
$$
\zeta(s) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^{s}} = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}
$$
It is easy to show that $\zeta(s)$ absolutely converges for $\Re(s) > 1$, while the *local* zeta function 
$$
\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = 1 + \frac{1}{p^{s}} + \frac{1}{p^{2s}} + \cdots 
$$
converges for $\Re(s) > 0$.

Comment: @reuns I'm sorry but I didn't get it. How does it explain the 1-gap between convergence regions of local and global zeta functions?

Comment: When removing the infinite places it is what happens with $\Phi(x) = 1_{x \in O}$. Let $O = \prod_{v < \infty} O_v= \{ x \in \Bbb{A_{fin}}, |x|_v \le 1\}$ the integers of finite adeles then $|x| = \prod_v |x|_v=|O/(x)|^{-1}$ and  $d^\times x$ is chosen such that $\int_{x \in O, |x|=1} d^\times x=1$ so $\int_{x \in O, |x|=n} d^\times x\le N^{\Omega(n)}$ where $N$ is the maximum number of places above $p$
and
$\int_O |x|^s d^\times x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}\int_{|x|=n^{-1}}n^{-s} d^\times x \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} N^{\Omega(n)} = \prod_p (1+\sum_{k \ge 1} N^k p^{-sk}) \le \zeta(s)^N$.